# how to Display ListFragment + Fragment by selecting tab on action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-listfragment

I am new to android.Please suggest me how to display ListFragment and Frgament on selecting the tab on action bar. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). It has samples, too.